# What is the imitater useful for?

Tags: plants-vs-zombies

I have just bought the imitater from twididinkies but I don't know what to use it  for. It says it lets you use 2 of the same plants in a single level but I don't know why I will want to use 2 of the same plants in a single level because that will just waste a seed slot. What is the imitater useful for?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are a few reasons depending on the level you are playing.
The main reason I personally used them was for pumpkin armor increasing the survivability of your defenses.

But other good options would be:

- Sunflowers/Sun Shrooms at the start of the level to boost production.
- Potato mines for cheap early game defenses
- Marigolds for extra money farming
- Or extra emergency buttons (Jalapeno, Cherry Bomb, Hypno Shroom or
  squash)

Usually you won't be needing them but they can be useful for getting certain achievements easier. But besides the achievements they are mainly used in endless levels where in each round you focus on a certain type of defensive wall.

Answer (score 3):

Imitater shroom has a fixed sun amount. It is useful because it's cooldown is not in sync with the copy plant's cooldown.
It can be used as an extra plant. If the plant you copy is used constantly, the IMitater can be used as an extra when its needed, but its on cooldown.

Comment: I know you want to answer my questions but we have different versions of plants vs zombies so I cannot completely rely on your answers. However, I would like to thank you for helping so I hope you keep answering my questions. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome. Also, A meta post from one of your comments got popular, may wanna see that...

Comment: Where is it in meta? Who posted it?

Comment: Its https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15420/how-should-we-respond-to-users-reprimanding-other-users-in-comments?cb=1